# How to dynamically change React Native transform with state?

Tags: react-native

I'm building a custom view that will rotate its contents based on device orientation. This app has orientation locked to portrait and I just want to rotate a single view. It fetches the current device orientation, updates the state, then renders the new component with the updated `style={{transform: [{rotate: 'xxxdeg'}]}}`.

I'm using `react-native-orientation-locker` to detect orientation changes.

The view renders correctly rotated on the first render. For example, if the screen loads while the device is rotated, it will render the view rotated. But upon changing the orientation of the device or simulator, the view does not rotate. It stays locked at the `rotate` value it was initialized at.

It seems like updates to the `transform` `rotate` value do not change the rotation. I've verified that new `rotate` values are present during the render. I've verified that orientation changes are correctly updating the state. But the view is never rotated in the UI when orientation changes. It is as if React Native isn't picking up on changes to the `rotate` value during a render.

I would expect that updates to the `rotate` value would rotate the `View` accordingly but that does not seem to be the case. Is there another way to accomplish this or do I have a bug in this code?

Edit: Is it required for `rotate` to be an `Animated` value?

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';

const RotateView = props => {
  const getRotation = newOrientation => {
    switch (newOrientation) {
      case 'LANDSCAPE-LEFT':
        return '90deg';
      case 'LANDSCAPE-RIGHT':
        return '-90deg';
      default:
        return '0deg';
    }
  };

  const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState(
    // set orientation to the initial device orientation
    Orientation.getInitialOrientation(),
  );
  const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(
    // set rotation to the initial rotation value (xxdeg)
    getRotation(Orientation.getInitialOrientation()),
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set up listeners for device orientation changes
    Orientation.addDeviceOrientationListener(setOrientation);
    return () => Orientation.removeDeviceOrientationListener(setOrientation);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // when orientation changes, update the rotation
    setRotate(getRotation(orientation));
  }, [orientation]);

  // render the view with the current rotation value
  return (
    <View style={{transform: [{rotate}]}}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};

export default RotateView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my completed component that handles rotation. It will rotate its children based on device orientation while the app is locked to portrait. I'm sure this could be cleaned up some but it works for my purposes.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {Animated, Easing, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Orientation} from '../utility/constants';
import OrientationManager from '../utility/orientation';

const OrientedView = (props) => {
  const getRotation = useRef((newOrientation) => {
    switch (newOrientation) {
      case Orientation.LANDSCAPE_LEFT:
        return 90;
      case Orientation.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT:
        return -90;
      default:
        return 0;
    }
  });
  const {duration = 100, style} = props;
  const initialized = useRef(false);
  const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState();
  const [rotate, setRotate] = useState();
  const [containerStyle, setContainerStyle] = useState(styles.containerStyle);
  // Animation kept as a ref
  const rotationAnim = useRef();
  // listen for orientation changes and update state
  useEffect(() => {
    OrientationManager.getDeviceOrientation((initialOrientation) => {
      const initialRotation = getRotation.current(initialOrientation);
      // default the rotation based on initial orientation
      setRotate(initialRotation);
      rotationAnim.current = new Animated.Value(initialRotation);
      setContainerStyle([
        styles.containerStyle,
        {
          transform: [{rotate: `${initialRotation}deg`}],
        },
      ]);
      initialized.current = true;
      // set orientation and trigger the first render
      setOrientation(initialOrientation);
    });
    OrientationManager.addDeviceOrientationListener(setOrientation);
    return () =>
      OrientationManager.removeDeviceOrientationListener(setOrientation);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialized.current === true) {
      const rotation = getRotation.current(orientation);
      setRotate(
        rotationAnim.current.interpolate({
          inputRange: [-90, 0, 90],
          outputRange: ['-90deg', '0deg', '90deg'],
        }),
      );
      Animated.timing(rotationAnim.current, {
        toValue: rotation,
        duration: duration,
        easing: Easing.ease,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    }
  }, [duration, orientation]);

  // FIXME: This is causing unnessary animation outside of the oriented view. Disabling removes the scale animation.
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   applyLayoutAnimation.current();
  // }, [orientation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialized.current === true) {
      setContainerStyle([
        styles.containerStyle,
        {
          transform: [{rotate}],
        },
      ]);
    }
  }, [rotate]);

  if (initialized.current === false) {
    return <View style={[containerStyle, style]} />;
  }

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[containerStyle, style]}>
      {props.children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerStyle: {flex: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'},
});

export default OrientedView;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and solved it by using an Animated.View from react-native-reanimated. (Animated.View from the standard react-native package might also work, but I haven't checked). I didn't need to use an Animated value, I still just used the actual value from the state, and it worked.

Comment: Works great! Using Animated.View from the react-native-reanimated library fixes the issue and allows my View to rotate by a an angle every time the angle is updated. 

I tested the default Animated.View from the standard react-native but that didn't work so I think something is bugged with the main react-native library.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Animated.Value` + `Animated.View` directly from react native you'll be fine.
Had the same issue and solved it using an `Animated.Value` class field (in your case I guess you'd use a `useState` for this one since functional + a `useEffect` to set the value of the `Animated.Value` upon changes in `props.rotation`), and then pass that into the `Animated.View` as the `transform = [{ rotate: animatedRotationValue }]`

Here's the class component form of this as a snippet:

```js
interface Props {
    rotation: number;
}

class SomethingThatNeedsRotation extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
    rotation = new Animated.Value(0);
    rotationValue = this.rotation.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 2 * Math.PI],
        outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
    });

    render() {
        this.rotation.setValue(this.props.rotation);
        const transform = [{ rotate: this.rotationValue }];
        
        return (
            <Animated.View style={{ transform }} />
        );
    }
}
```

Note that in my example I also have the interpolation there since my input is in radians and I wanted it to be in degrees.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, as the rotation is supposed to change when the value of `rotate` updates. A workaround is to set the View's `key` attribute to the rotate value as well.

For example:

```
return (
  <View
    key={rotate} // <~~~ fix!
    style={{transform: [{rotate}]}}
  >
    {props.children}
  </View>
)
```

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27003#issuecomment-560936653).